# How to escape < or > in a parameter in shell?

Tags: shell, quoting, escape-characters, parameter

I'd like to use `grep` with a PCRE expression that contains the `<` character. Bash thinks I want to redirect, but I don't want to. How can I escape `<`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to do it with a backslash:

```
25 % grep \< xmospos.c
#include        <stdio.h>
#include        <stdlib.h>
#include        <getopt.h>
#include        <X11/Xlib.h>
```

A quoted less-than, and a quoted, backslashed less than both gave goofy answers.

Comment: Yes, or put it in single quotes

Comment: I still need to learn, e.g. how that exactly works with escaping: `grep -oP '(?< )(.*)$'` does not work with single quotes for example. Tried it at first.

Comment: @hakre There seems to be a syntax error in your regexp. Did you mean `(?<! )(.*)$` or `(?<= )(.*)$`?

Answer (score 4):

Two simple rules:

- A backslash `\C` escapes the next character, whatever it is, other than a newline.
- Single quotes `'text'` escape any character between them, including a backslash, but not including a single quote (since it marks the end of the quoted text).

Thus:

```
grep -P '<html>' myfile
grep -P \<html\> myfile
grep -P '(?<!<)html' myfile
grep -P \(\?\<\!\<\) myfile
```

If you need to pass an argument that contains single quotes, you can use `'\''` to “escape” a single quote inside single quotes. Technically, what this does is end the first literal text, then put a literal `'` in the same word, then more literal text still in the same word.

```
grep '^D'\''oh!' myfile
```

The rest of the quoting rules (summarized):

- You need to quote the following characters at least some of the times: whitespace and `` !"#$&'()*;<>?[\]^`{|}~ `` (in other words, the following characters are safe: letters, digits, `%+,-./:=@_` and non-ASCII characters).
- Between double quotes, all characters are used literally except `` "$\` `` and (in shells with history enabled) `!`. A backslash between double quotes will appear in the string unless it precedes one of the non-literal characters.

These rules are for bash and other Bourne-style shells (such as ash and ksh). They apply to zsh as well (except that `=` after whitespace may need quoting). The rules in csh/tcsh and in Fish are different.